# How to solve this double integral over general region?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Evaluate
> $$
> \iint _R \frac{xy^2}{(4x^2+y^2)^2}\,dA,
> $$where $R$ is the finite region enclosed by the parabola $y=x^2$ and the line $y=2x$.

So far I have figured out the $R$ (if I am correct) as $0\le x\le 2$ and $x^2\le y\le 2x$ but I'm stuck on how to calculate the double integral. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I haven't really tried, but it seems like it would be much easier to find an antiderivative if you write the region so that you integrate with respect to $x$ first, rather than $y$. (I.e., you go from the left boundary curve to the right, rather than from the bottom to the top.)

Comment: @HansLundmark ahhh I didn't think about using type II region, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most easy is to integrate firstly by one variable and then by another:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{2}\,dx\int\limits_{x^2}^{2x}\frac{xy^2}{(4x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy=
\int\limits_{0}^{4}\,dy\int\limits_{\frac{y}{2}}^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{xy^2}{(4x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx$$